Create an i graph object with sf objects using the i graph package in R to perform a network analysis
I would like to create an i graph object out of two sf objects. The first one includes the edges represented by polylines, in that case rivers. The second one includes vertices that lie on the river network. In the end I would like to measure the distances between the vertices on the river network.
I prepared the edge list by creating two columns at the left handside of the data table. One is called stream and the other next_stream. This is the link for mocking data: https://we.tl/t-3C5bs8dOAI
When i try to create the i graph object with the function graph_from_data_frame i get the error message:
Error in graph_from_data_frame(d = EL_ID, directed = FALSE, vertices = VL_ID) :
Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame
In addition: Warning message:
In graph_from_data_frame(d = EL_ID, directed = FALSE, vertices = VL_ID) :
In d' NA' elements were replaced with string "NA
How do I prepare my data in the first place to run the i graph command?
The code:
#prepare data
VerticeList <- st_read("vertices")
EdgeList <- st_read("rivers")

VL_ID <- VerticesList%>%
  mutate(ID=1:nrow(.))

EL_ID <- EdgeList%>%
  mutate(stream=1:nrow(.),.before=OBJECTID)%>%
  mutate(next_stream=NA,.before=OBJECTID)

#create network
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d=EL_ID, directed = FALSE, vertices = VL_ID)

#data environment
> EL_ID
Simple feature collection with 558 features and 120 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 282440.2 ymin: 5563690 xmax: 502924.3 ymax: 5726573
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N

> VL_ID
Simple feature collection with 7895 features and 49 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 283048.5 ymin: 5563731 xmax: 502685.5 ymax: 5725958
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N


Struggling to understand what your code is trying to do here. What do you expect the g object (created from graph_from_data_frame) to look like? Is it not what you want? If you can't share your full data sets can you show a small example that typifies what you have?

In a next step I would like to use the i graph object with the package hydrographr to meausre the distances between the vertices on the river network. I do not really know what I expect from the g object. I just want to prepare my data for network analysis.

Did you check the R package sfnetworks?
